# DISTINCT query on multiple columns doesn't work - Google App engine Datastore

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints

I want to fetch distinct multiple columns from Google app engine Datastore in `endpoint` class. For that i am using below code but problem is that if i try to fetch only single column then only it works properly and returns DISTINCT data. If i try to fetch multiple columns then `DISTINCT` doesn't work and it returns all records without any effect of Distinct query. I don't know what is wrong with my code. Please suggest any solution and guide me where i am going wrong. 
Thank you.

Code:

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
    @ApiMethod(name = "getDistinctFollow", httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET, path = "userendpoint/userName_fk3")
    public ObjectListContainer getDistinctFollower(
            @Named("followName") ArrayList<String> lstFollower,
            @Nullable @Named("cursor") String cursorString,
            @Nullable @Named("limit") Integer limit) {

        EntityManager mgr = null;
        Cursor cursor = null;
        List<Object[]> lstNames;
        List<String> lstString;
        ObjectListContainer object;
        try {
            mgr = getEntityManager();
            Query query = mgr.createQuery("select distinct f.uFullName,f.uUrl from UMaster f where f.uName in (:followName)");
            query.setParameter("followName", lstFollower);
            if (cursorString != null && cursorString != "") {
                cursor = Cursor.fromWebSafeString(cursorString);
                query.setHint(JPACursorHelper.CURSOR_HINT, cursor);
            }
            if (limit != null) {
                query.setFirstResult(0);
                query.setMaxResults(limit);
            }
            lstNames = (List<Object[]>) query.getResultList();
            cursor = JPACursorHelper.getCursor(lstNames);
            if (cursor != null)
                cursorString = cursor.toWebSafeString();

            lstString = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (Object obj[] : lstNames) {
                lstString.add(obj != null ? obj[0].toString() : null);
                lstString.add(obj != null ? obj[1].toString() : null);
            }
            object = new ObjectListContainer();
            object.setObjectsList(lstString);

        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }
        return object;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure anything's wrong with your code, but the DISTINCT keyword is still experimental as mentioned in the documentation, so maybe there is an issue with this kind of query. Maybe you can try not projecting on specific columns but retrieving all columns to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the issue, but DISTINCT with multiple parameters will return distinct tuples. So in your query it is supposed to return every distinct pair of (uFullName, uUrl). Can you provide what duplicates are being returned?

Comment: @PatrickCostello when i use `DISTINCT` with single column then it returns distinct data but if i use it with multiple columns then it returns duplicates.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of the data returned?

Comment: @PatrickCostello I am using NoSql in app engine. There is a total 12 records with `userName = abc`.If i use only `Distint uFullName where uName = 'abc'` then it returns single record with value and if i use `Distinct uFullName,uUrl where uName = 'abc'` then it returns all 12 record without any effect of distinct query.

Comment: So to clarify, those 12 records also have the same uUrl?

Comment: yes,those 12 records have same uUrl.

Comment: I think this may be a JPA issue: Can you try a test run of the query using the low level java API: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/

Answer (score 0):

Notice that `DISTINCT` only works with Indexed properties. Is any of `uFullName` or `uName` are not indexed, then the projection won't work.